# Missing form fields for titles

Tags: sylius

I've installed Sylius (http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/book/installation.html) and form fields for category and product title are missing. It is missing from HTML. Someone please help :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: In your product form there is sylius.form.product.translation which corresponds to the product name. And in Taxonomy you have the Name field, there is no Title field in the Taxonomy entity, just name.

Comment: I am sorry for misleading title. Of coure it is name field. The problem is that all name fields in administration are missing. Even the one in Product archetypes. Do you have any suggestions how should I fix the problem?

Comment: Did you load the fixtures without errors? Try loading them manually: `php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load`

Comment: OK, the problem is...
loading [60] Sylius\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadOrdersData                                                    
  [OutOfBoundsException]                            
  Reference to: (Sylius.Country.BV) does not exist

Comment: The problem was with language codes. I have reinstalled Sylius and set the  default ones and it works.